# Format blocks of text in accordance with its [PREFIX]-name

Tags: regex, powershell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file formatted like this

```
[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director
https://yyyy.cc/CD1.html

Link;AA.part1.rar;BB;
Link;AA.part2.rev;CC;

https://yyyy.com/wqAk848v

Link;BB.part1.rar;BB;
Link;BB.part2.rev;CC;

[PC] Halflife
https://yyyy.com/wqAk848v

Link;XX.part5.rar;VV;
Link;XX.part6.rev;DD;
......
```

I try to format text in this way

```
[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director
https://yyyy.cc/CD1.html

[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director;Link;AA.part1.rar;BB;
[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director;Link;AA.part2.rev;CC;

https://yyyy.com/wqAk848v

[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director;Link;BB.part1.rar;BB;
[PC] AeternoBlade II: Director;Link;BB.part2.rev;CC;

[PC] Halflife
https://yyyy.com/wqAk848v

[PC] Halflife;Link;XX.part5.rar;VV;
[PC] Halflife;Link;XX.part6.rev;DD;
```

I have a filename that begins always with [PC], however with a standard prefix followed by its links below.
I try to add [PREFIX]-*name* before `Link;`

Can anybody put me on the right track to achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\[PC\]/h;/^Link/{G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2;\1/}' file
```

Make a copy of the most recent line beginning `[PC]`.

If a line begins 'Link', append the copied line and using pattern matching manipulate it into the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^\[PC\]/ { head=$0 } /^Link/ { $0=head";"$0 }1' file
```

Search for lines beginning with "[PC]" and set the variable head to the line ($0). Then when a line starts with "Link", Set the line ($0) to the variable head, a ";" and then the line. Print all results with 1

Comment: I try to run your command `awk "/^\[PC\]/ { head=$0 } /^Link/ { $0=head";"$0 }1" listax.txt > output.txt` but it return a wrong output, look here why https://pastebin.com/raw/BFq0MsE0

Comment: Make sure you are using single and not double quotes.

Comment: ah, ok, I try to test now under linux